# Python Web Proxy that Supports PKCS#11

Tags: python, proxy, smartcard, pkcs#11

Does anyone know of a web proxy written in Python that will support SSL connections and will also support PKCS#11 tokens? I am in need of a proxy that will send SSL web requests using a PKCS#11 smartcard.

I have been looking for projects that are using something like Twisted but have not seen any.

Answer (score 0):

If Twisted has a proxy, then you can use it with M2Crypto+engine_pkcs11. I had the code, I can see if it is still existing somewhere.